# Home page question display could differentiate users by type

Tags: discussion, question-lists

On the home page right now you see question specific stats (votes, answers, views, titles, tags, time, user name, reputation). Only three of these is varied by type, there's the red, no answers box, the golden accepted answer text, the ignored and interested tags highlighting and the bounty in the title.

I'd like to see a little more of this for the other details. Notably the negative voting status of a question could be a little more obvious. Additionally I'd like to have it indicated if the user is new to this. There's a few ways this could happen:

1. The user's rep is visible, if it's below 100 maybe their author tagline (div class="started" box) could be highlighted a little. Personally I can't visually judge a user's rep as low as quickly as I can spot there's a `k` or no `k` in the rep.
2. If this is one of the user's first `n` questions the same box might be highlighted.
3. If this user has never answered a question or has less than `m` questions some indication might be useful too.

I understand that the first concern is that we don't want people ignoring new users just because they're new, so personally I hope it wouldn't be a red-flag style of highlight, but more of a be-a-little-understanding kind of indication.  On the other hand, when you see a question that is not one of the first `n` but the user hasn't answered `m` times yet, that might be something that will clue you in to the fact that they might not even know how to ask a question well yet, or have no interest in other people's problems.

It's a thought.

**Update** oops. I forgot that the user tag line on the homepage doesn't stay as the user who asked the question, but rather changes to the last person who asked or answered on that question. This makes the highlighting of user-type I was just talking about less relevant.

Comment: Had to downvote this to check the negative voting status. Just a moment... mmh... obvious!

Comment: That's probably a matter of opinion, it's obvious if you're looking for the negative, but less so next to double digit ones.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, questions should be answered and posts should be voted solely based on their merit as questions and answers, not by considering their author.

While it's a good thing to prevent abusive behavior, as done by the accept rate, what you are suggesting is basically choosing not to visit a post merely by looking at its author on the home page.

Comment: Or the opposite. IE on Stackoverflow I'm fairly confident because I know even if the question sucks I am now able to edit it to suck less. On ServerFault I can't edit it, and I'd rather not want to.